# math.power gives an unexpected result

Tags: java

I don't see why my output is a factor 100 lower than makes sense.

```
public class Solution{

    public static void main(String []args){
       String jj = "";

       for(double k=0;k<10;k++){
          double kk = Math.pow(k, 2);
          jj = jj + kk;
       }   

       System.out.println(jj);
    }
}
```

I expected to simply get the squares of the first 11 integers

Comment: What output do you expect? The last number is 81 and that is fine with your abort condition. Why do you expect 11 numbers? How many number do you think are between 0 and <10 (== 9 max)?

Comment: You're only doing the first 10 squares btw, not 11.

Comment: "is a factor 100 lower than makes sense" - No, it is not. Just add some spacing between your concatenation `jj = jj + "  " +kk;` or cast double to int.

Answer (score 2):

Your current `for` is from 0 to 10 (not included), so 10 values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).

If you want to include the 10 value, change the end condition of the `for` to `k <= 10` or `k < 11`.

- There is no reason to use `double` for `k`
- Cast the result of `Math.pow` to `long`
- Add an empty space between the numbers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jj = "";

    for (int k = 0; k <= 10; k++) {
        long kk = (long) Math.pow(k, 2);
        jj = jj + " " + kk;
    }
    System.out.println(jj);
}
```

Output

```
0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

Comment: Note that it is preferable to use `k * k` here, rather than `Math.pow(k, 2)`. it is more concise *and* produces a result of the correct type (there is no need to use `long`, `int` is sufficient).